# Is there a way to plot from Codeclocks to Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, polyhedra

So I've written a C++ code that given a concave Polyhedron decomposes it in convex polyhedra which I save in a list. Now I wanted to plot the Polyhedra that I obtain from this decomposition on Matlab to see if my Algorithm works. Does someone now if I can make this and how?

Comment: Save the data into a file and load it with whatever you want to use for plotting.

Comment: You could plot it from C++ without Matlab with https://matplotlib-cpp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/